# Blender 2.8 - Texture not showing up on material preview, neither exporting to .fbx file

Tags: texturing, materials, export

(Ok, so i've looked it up, and none of the answers to other simillar questions helped. I'm getting desesperate)

I created this model on Blender 2.8. I configured the material settings, unwraped the texture in uv map, assigned materials and everything. The textures are properly shown on shading mode, but on material preview it doesn't show up, neither when i try to export to a .fbx file. But the texture of the shirt is working. Nodes are enabled. All settings look the same, i can't find out what's wrong.

[image]

[image]

[Project File Link](https://easyupload.io/zmwg69) Please, i need help!

//Edit: the texture was showing up on material preview before.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. I can see the texture (eyes) on the model in the 3D view. The material preview (sphere) does not have a *FaceUVmap* like your model, so the texture is not positioned correctly and thus not visible. It seems your problem lies within the fbx export. Have you read the answer to [this fbx export question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/57531/30849)?

Comment: It was showing up on material preview before. I already exported models with textures before and didn't have this issue. I don't know if it's because i used more than one uv map this time. I read this, and i understand the problem when exporting materials and i usually have to create new materials on Unity, but i actually don't care for material settings, i only need the face texture to be exported properly. But, the shirt texture is exported properly, and that makes wonder what in heaven is going on.

Comment: I found out that it's not showing up on material preview anymore because i attached the uv map, now i get it. But it still doesn't export the face texture, but exports the shirt texture.

Comment: FBX only supports a single texture image. Is the shirt texture perhaps marked as the [active render](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/uv/uv_texture_spaces.html#uv-maps-panel) texture?

Comment: Yes, it's marked, but it's assigned to the body. The head is a separated object, and its active render texture is the face texture. Do you mean that, even though i have two objects, i can only export one texture?

Comment: I delleted all the other uv maps and it worked, thank you! Thank you really really much. I didn't know i couldn't export more than one texture in a .fbx file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much guys! I didn't know i couldn't export more than one uv map on an .fbx file. Now that i delleted all the other uv maps, the face texture is finally showing up when i export the file. I really appreciated your help. Thank you!